# Is there any method to generate pdf in react native app?

Tags: react-native, pdf, expo

I am making an expense tracker app in which i want a pdf report of all the transactions to be generated. So i am trying a demo use of pdf print using expo with the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Print } from 'expo-print';

export default function Pdf() {

  async function createPDF() {

    let filePath = await Print.printToFileAsync({
      html: "<h1>PDF TEST</h1>",
      width : 612,
      height : 792,
      base64 : false
    });

    alert('PDF Generated', filePath.uri);
  }

  
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={createPDF} style={styles.Main}>
          <Text>Create PDF</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Main : { marginTop : 100 }
});
```

But the error keep showing **Possible unhandled promise rejection (id 0) typeerror undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoPrint.Print.printToFileAsync')**.
I couldnt understand whats the major issue is. I hate added the Read and Write user permissions too but it keep showing this error.

Comment: Can you try to use :  "import * as Print from 'expo-print';" instead of "import { Print } from 'expo-print';"

Comment: Thanks it works but i cannot see the file where it had been saved neither i can view it. Do you have any idea about it?